# cout: the last string cover the first string

Tags: c++, string, cout

I want to read string in a file using c++.
The input string like: "File: blacksburg.asc"
I need to read string after ":"
Part of my code as following:

```css
 void mapWalk( string input, string output ){
        ifstream in(input.c_str());
        string line;
        string mapdata = "";
        getline(in,line);
        int pos = line.find(":");
        mapdata = line.substr(pos);
        cout<<"The string is"<< mapdata <<"&&" << endl;     
   }
```

The output is shown as following:
&&e string is: blacksburg.asc

It is so wired!!
Why && is at begin of the string and cover the other?

Does someone have ideas?

Comment: Can you give us enough code to replicate the problem? What is in the line that's read in? What type is `line`? And so on.

Comment: Do you have an executable sample ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a carriage return character at the end of `mapdata`. So you output "The string is", then the contents of `mapdata` including the carriage return. Then you output `&&` on top of the previous text because you returned the carriage without a line feed.

Read the documentation for `getline`. It specifies that the line ending is not removed.